# Error while trying to print the results in R's Antitrust Package

Tags: r, simulation, economics

I'm using R's Package `Antitrust` for calculating demand own and cross price elasticities and printing the summary results of a merger between firms. The model used is PC-AIDS (Proportionally Calibrated Almost Ideal Demand System), published by [Epstein and Rubinfeld (2007)](http://royepstein.com/ALJ_final_proof.pdf). It is a brand-level simulation and companies are allowed owning more than one brand in the standard simulation, as I've seen in excel. My wish is to print the results adequately, in a merger between two firms and one of them owning more than one brand (pre-merger).

My problem, though, seems to be a problem of programming/understanding the output of the code. I'll post a similar code of what I have done:

```
require(antitrust)

ownerPre<-c("a","a","b","c")

ownerPost<-c("a","a","a","c")

shares<-c(0.30,0.20,0.20,0.30)

knownelast<- -1.5
mktelast  <- -1.0

results<-pcaids(shares,knownelast, mktelast, ownerPre=ownerPre,ownerPost=ownerPost,
               labels=ownerPre,knownElastIndex=1)
resume<-summary(results)

resume
```

And after the line of `results<-summary(results)`, I get the following error in my output window:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘* a’
```

`summary(results)` holds results of price variation, output variation etc.

Maybe `Antitrust` is not pre-programed similarly to other versions I've seen of PC-AIDS and maybe I cannot obtain such results from this package -- making the exercise of writing this question almost pointless. But if this is by any chance a programming issue, in which someone more experienced in R might help, I invite a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue printing data.frame objects when the row name is the same:

```
mat <- matrix(1:10, ncol=2)
mat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10

rownames(mat) <- rep("a", 5)
mat
  [,1] [,2]
a    1    6
a    2    7
a    3    8
a    4    9
a    5   10
```

Now let's make it a data.frame:

```
temp <- as.data.frame(mat)
temp
```

> Error in data.frame(V1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), V2 = c(" 6", " 7",  : 
>         duplicate row.names: a

The solution for your problem is to rename the labels so that each is distinct:

```
ownerPreLab <- c("a.1","a.2","b","c")

results <- pcaids(shares, knownelast, mktelast, ownerPre=ownerPre, ownerPost=ownerPost,
                  labels=ownerPreLab, knownElastIndex=1)

resume<-summary(results)

Merger simulation results under 'PCAIDS' demand:

      priceDelta sharesPre sharesPost outputDelta
* a.1         44        30         29        -2.4
* a.2         44        20         20        -2.4
* b           81        20         16       -18.4
  c           11        30         35        16.4

    Notes: '*' indicates merging parties' products. Deltas are percent changes.
    Output is based on revenues.


Share-Weighted Price Change:    38.55
Share-Weighted CMCR:    37.58
```